# Batch: Set password with special characters to variable

Tags: windows, batch-file

So in batch there are a lot of special characters that are reserved and cause issues if you use them, if I want to set up a password like so:

SET PASSWORD="123%6!@##$^&*_-"

Some of these characters will be stripped after assignment for example the percent '%' character is interpreted as a parameter, is there a way to make batch see that as a string instead of interpreting special characters? no I cannot escape those special characters, this is basically a file that we tell the user to edit teh batch file and set the password.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Echo exact string in windows batch file?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9757480/echo-exact-string-in-windows-batch-file)

Comment: Essentially, you're on a wild-goose chase. Since the user can put any characters into the file, you need to deal with all of the possibilities for special characters - no doubt a way could be found to correctly process each one, but consider [`"=%^&*?)~:\/<>,;`] and of course Space. Character-case, too. A nightmare - some other method needed, I'd recommend.

Answer (score 1):

You could use some *magic* batch functions to handle with any string, like [magic echo](http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6446).

But I suppose it's better that the user doesn't edit the batch file itself, instead edit a password file, like `pwd.txt`.
Then you can read this file simply with:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set /p password= < pwd.txt
echo !password!
```

This read the first line of the file and has no problems with any character.